# Realizar el Join de un par de tablas, resultado en DataFrame y Spark sql

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

¿Cómo puedo realizar el `Join` de una tabla llamada "*TABLA_X*" con "*TABLA_Y*" a través del campo `col_A_id`?

Teniendo en cuenta los siguientes puntos:

-Considerar rendimiento
-TABLA_X:30GB
-TABLA_Y:15MB
-Solución con dataframe y spark sql

No encuentro la documentación adecuada, tengo un ejemplo de dataframe, realizado en un curso pero no mide nada de rendimiento ni como hacer `Joins`

```sql
display(
    df
        .select(df["Country"],df["Description"],df["UnitPrice"]*(df["Quantity"]).alias("Total"))
        .groupBy("Country","Description")
        .sum()
        .filter(df["Country"]=="United Kingdom")
        .sort("sum(Total)",ascending=False)
        .limit(10)
)
```

¿Alguien sabe donde puedo encontrar la documentación adecuada?

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He realizado varios join de tablas que pueden ser muy pesadas, mi recomendacion es que realices el join, una vez con el dataframe que resulta podras realizar los select de la columnas, groupBY, sort y demas, porque estara cargado en memoria y sera realmente muy rapido.

Por otro lado, para realizar joins, deberas conocer la teoria, te dejo un enlace donde explica bastante bien:
http://kirillpavlov.com/blog/2016/04/23/beyond-traditional-join-with-apache-spark/

Para realizar un join de dataframe :

```
val daframeResult= DataframeTABLA_X
        .join(DataframeTABLA_Y, Seq("col_A_id"))
```

Si no especificas nada, tomara como default el "inner", ahora bien te he dejado la teoria para que puedas tener en cuenta , que en un join podras querer solo la parte izquierda, o derecha.

```
val daframeResult= DataframeTABLA_X
        .join(DataframeTABLA_Y, Seq("col_A_id", *joinType =* "left_anti")))//para quedarte con la parte izquierda solamente
```

Espero que sirva la informacion.-